# React-native: realm. UserProvider fallback component not rendering when user is not logged in

Tags: react-native, expo, realm

Im working on a react-native expo app and have installed realm to implement mongo-db login.

my code is:
App.tsx:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AppWrapper from './src/AppWrapper';
import { SYNC_CONFIG } from './src/configs/sync.config';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <AppWrapper appId={SYNC_CONFIG.appId}/>
  );
}
```

AppWrapper.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppProvider, UserProvider } from '@realm/react';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { RealmProvider } from '@realm/react';
import { OpenRealmBehaviorType, OpenRealmTimeOutBehavior } from 'realm';

import Login from './screens/Login';
import App from './screens/App';
export const AppWrapper: React.FC<{
  appId: string;
}> = ({ appId }) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView className={'flex-1 bg-emerald-900'}>
      <AppProvider id={appId}>
        <UserProvider fallback={<Login />}>
          <App/>
        </UserProvider>
      </AppProvider>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default AppWrapper;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "pulsefit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@realm/react": "^0.6.2",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "realm": "^12.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The issue is that on the first render of app when the user is not logged in the fallback component Login should be rendered, but this is not happening. The App component is being rendered instead.
Can someone help me understand where Im going wrong here?

Comment: I would suggest following the [Realm Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/manage-users/authenticate-users/#set-up--realm-react-providers) and also ensure appId  is defined. Performing some basic troubleshooting may be revealing as well - stepping through the code line by line to see where it's failing would help. Spinkle in some output to console statements and see where the code goes awry.

Comment: I have followed the same Realm Documentation to write the above code.I logged the user details and that is undefined, and still the fallback component is not rendered.

Comment: It's going to be hard for us to troubleshoot. For example appid could be invalid which would cause it to fail. The [authentication documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/manage-users/authenticate-users/#set-up--realm-react-providers) shows slightly different code. If you use that exact code, does it work?